Strong and pointwise convergence in $L^p$ imply the sequence is bounded by a $L^p$ function
Say that $u_n\to u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ for some $p>1$ and also $u_n\to u$ pointwise a.e. on $\Omega$.
How can we prove that there is a function $f\in L^{p}(\Omega)$ such that:
$$|u_n|\leq f$$
a.e. on $\Omega$ for any $n\geq 1$?
I found this in proof as a straightforward step and I do not see why it is true.

What is $V_n$? If it is same as $u_n$, then  your statement is false.

One counter-example is available here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454152/seeking-counterexample-for-dominated-convergence-theorem

Here is a probabilistic example thanks to Davide Giraudo.
